# Microsoft Access VBA add data from form to tables unbound form

Tags: vba, ms-access, recordset

How can I use the data generated by the code and the user input to add the records to the deploymentStep table and to the deploymentPlan table?

I have table like the following

***PillarTeamDeploymentSteps***

| pillarTeam | pillarTeamStep | other info |
| --- | --- | --- |
| team 1 | step 1 |  |
| team 1 | step 2 |  |
| team 1 | step 3 |  |
| team 1 | step 4 |  |
| team 2 | step 1 |  |
| team 2 | step 2 |  |
| team 2 | step 3 |  |
| team 2 | step 4 |  |
| team 2 | step 5 |  |
| team 2 | step 6 |  |

And tables with the structure

***deploymentStep***

| pillarTeam | pillarTeamStep | deployment | endDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |

***deploymentPlan***

| pillarTeam | deployment | startDate | endDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |

Using a form I would like users to be able to select their team and have it autopopulate text fields with the corresponding pillarTeamSteps. This can be seen in the screenshots. [image]

[image]

After the user has selected a team and the steps have autopopulated they would manually input data in the date boxes. From here i'd like a button press to add the records. I am using the following code to update the forms visibile fields and values. There will be only a max steps of ten per team.

How can I use the data generated by the code and the user input to add the records to the deploymentStep table and to the deploymentPlan table?

```
Private Sub pillarTeam_AfterUpdate()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
Dim deploymentSteps As DAO.Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb

strSQL = "SELECT PillarTeamDeploymentSteps.pillarTeam, PillarTeamDeploymentSteps.pillarTeamStep, PillarTeamDeploymentSteps.deploymentType FROM PillarTeamDeploymentSteps WHERE (((PillarTeamDeploymentSteps.pillarTeam)=" & Me.pillarTeam & "))"

Debug.Print (strSQL)

Set RS = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
If Not (RS.EOF) Then
    RS.MoveLast
    RS.MoveFirst
End If



'setting visible controls
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If ctl.Tag < RS.RecordCount + 1 Or (ctl.Tag < RS.RecordCount + 21 And ctl.Tag >= 20) Then
        ctl.Visible = True
    Else
        ctl.Visible = False
    End If
Next ctl


With RS
    If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
    .MoveLast
    .MoveFirst
    While (Not .EOF)
        Debug.Print (RS.AbsolutePosition)
'populating deployment steps
        For Each ctl In Me.Controls
            If ctl.Tag = RS.AbsolutePosition Then
                ctl.Value = RS.Fields("pillarTeamStep")
            End If
            
         Next ctl
          
        .MoveNext
    Wend
        
        
    End If
    .Close
End With
    

    Set RS = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest binding form to deploymentPlan and have a subform bound to deploymentStep.

To 'batch' create records, use an INSERT SELECT action SQL.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO deploymentStep(pillarTeam, pillarTeamStep, deployment) " & _
                   "SELECT " & Me.tbxTeam & " AS T, pillarTeamStep, " & Me.tbxDeploymentID & " AS D " & _
                   "FROM PillarTeamDeploymentSteps " & _
                   "WHERE pillarTeam=" & Me.tbxTeam
```

This assumes pillarTeam and deployment are numeric identifiers such as Autonumber type. If not, then use apostrophe delimiters.

Trick here is first saving 'parent' deploymentPlan record and grabbing that record identifier to save as foreign key in deploymentStep.

Comment: So in this situation I would have my deploymentStep table bound to the form controls and have it be a continuous form? @june7

Comment: Thanks @June7 i think this is likely the best route forward I have marked the answer as correct. I appreciate the refined form setup.